# How to open a URL in google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1owEwaLhddXvSfI11AA7ZWmuQh4oeKoVSZkiu9LSlRLU/edit?usp=sharing   ]

This is my sheet in which i fill the start time for first row manually. I open the link manually for the first time and mark my judgement for "Purchasable" Column as Y/N. As soon as i mark my judgement i want the "end time" column to fill automatically and the link in the "URL" column of the next row to open up automatically and repeat the same series. Is it possible by app script as I need to perform this task on google spreadsheet.

```
if(r.getColumn()==4){
var endCell=r.offset(0,4);
if(endCell.getValue()==='')
var date=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),timezone,timestamp_format);
endCell.setValue(date);
var startCell=r.offset(1,-1);
startCell.setValue(date);
```

Now this could fill up the start and end time for a sample when i fill up the purchasable Column but I cant figure out how to open the next URL without clicking on it ??

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1owEwaLhddXvSfI11AA7ZWmuQh4oeKoVSZkiu9LSlRLU/edit#gid=0

This is my sheet.

Comment: Your link is inaccessible. If possible, you should post your data as text directly into your post, rather than posting a link.

Comment: Now it is accessible. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: I cannot access it. Can you check your settings again?

Comment: What would be code for that?

Comment: @Chef1075 Now you can access it

Comment: You can not directly open a new browser tab or browser window from server side Apps Script code.  You could use an On Edit trigger that opened up a dialog box, and the dialog box would run an "onload" command that then opened a new browser tab and then closed the dialog box.  That is the only way to do it.

Comment: can you provide me with the code to do that? @SandyGood

Answer (score 0):

I have non-coding solution to this problem that only takes a couple of clicks.

In this [sheet I have](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1goovSgBgBpLfUpmFXPla_tSk45zv_W2cRHUkk-iywuA/edit?usp=sharing) put on the end time column the formula =now(). When you change the yes or no column the end time column will update automatically. All you need to do is click on the timestamp for that row press ctrl+c to copy and ctrl+shift+v to paste. This will paste just the time without the formula making the timestamp permanent.

Comment: Is there any command that could automate the opening of the URL ?

Answer (score 0):

As Sandy said, "You can not directly open a new browser tab or browser window from server side Apps Script code." 
The only solution to my knowledge is to open a dialog box which in turn automate the opening of the URL. But you will see the popup of the dialog box in the spreadsheet UI until the URL is opened.

code.gs

```
function open_dialog()
{
    var temp_dialog = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("temp_dialog").setTitle("everw");
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(temp_dialog,"Name");
}
```

temp_dialog.html

```
<html>
  <a href="Replace_the_url" id="link" target="_blank" ></a> 
</html>
<script>
  document.getElementById("link").click();
  google.script.host.close();
</script>
```

Comment: express.google.com/product/15004630315996151317_0_8175035?eflags=LOCATION_SERVICE_USER_TAGS:POGXONBOARDING|POGX|WALMART 
It is the link that doesn't open by script but it does open when clicked directly from the sheet. It shows ERROR 400. Can you help?

Comment: Have edited a bit in the code.Can you try again by replacing the "href" value with your URL.

Comment: Error 400. The requested URL is not found on this server.

Is this happening because Google has tightened its security??
Otherwise the URL is opening just fine in the browser when "clicked" from the spreadsheet.

Comment: May I know from which context are you calling this method. I didn't get any such error when I tried and the code works fine.

Comment: I am calling it by an onClick button by putting this link in the Spreadsheet. I have also tried  <a href="Replace_the_url" id="link" target="_blank" ></a> method and got the same result. But the link is shown very correctly in the Logger.    Link= 
"express.google.com/product/15004630315996151317_0_8175035?ef‌​lags=LOCATION_SERVIC‌​E_USER_TAGS:POGXONBO‌​ARDING|POGX|WALMART" Try to open it by your method!

Comment: It worked fine for me and all I had to change was the URL at href=

Answer (score 0):

I have provided the code below. You can add this code on your script in Google Sheets etc. Add a Trigger or a button to it. 
Once the Script is Triggered it shall open a Browser tab with the desired URL.

```
function openNew() {
 var js = " \ 
    <script> \
     window.open('**https://exmaple.com**','_blank','width=800, height=600'); \
}) \
    </script> \
  ";
 var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(js)
    .setHeight(10)
    .setWidth(100);
 Logger.log(html);
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Now Loading'); // If you use this on Spreadsheet
}
```