# Open google form on submit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I would like to call another google form once submit is hit. Is this possible?

I've tried the code below; however nothing is happening. I'm wondering if it would be easier to open the form on a specific cell changing on google sheets.

```
function onSubmit() {
FormApp.openById("ID")
}
```

I have a specific form that when I hit submit, I would like it to call another specific form

Comment: What do you mean by "call" in this context? Do you want it to pop up for the user? Do you just want your script to interact with it?

Comment: I'm wanting it to pop up for the user.

Comment: Google forms seems to have added inbuilt support for adding a new form to old form recently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Apps Script "open" methods like `openById` open the referred document on the server side.

The workaround is to create a form that allows you to add client side code and for this, one alternative is to use the Google Apps Script HTML Service, i.e. you could create a web app.

Related

- [How to open a given Url?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13272748/1595451)
- [How to open a URL in google apps script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48045550/1595451)

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app#openbyidid
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Comment: Hi @Ruben, I'm getting a cannot call FormApp.getui from this context. 
`function onFormSubmit() {
var ui = FormApp.getUi();
  //.
  ui.createMenu('Menu')
      .addItem('Show Window', 'testNew')
      .addToUi();
}

function testNew(){
  showAnchor('Click this link to finish Provider request',C_URL);
}

function showAnchor(name,url) {
  var html = '<html><body><a href="'+url+'" target="blank" onclick="google.script.host.close()">'+name+'</a></body></html>';
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
  FormApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,"demo");  
}`

Comment: That is the way it works. If you need further help, post a new question.